# flutter_launcher_icons --- Error detected in pubspec.yaml:

Tags: flutter

Hi I’m trying to put an image as icon of the app but I’m not getting it.
Does anyone know how to fix the mistake?
Thank you.

```
name: unti
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flare_flutter: ^2.0.3
  page_transition: ^1.1.5
  path_provider: ^1.6.8
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  firebase_database: ^3.1.6
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - animacoes/
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
  flutter_icons:
    android: true
    ios: true
    image_path: "icons/logo2.png"
```

Hi I’m trying to put an image as icon of the app but I’m not getting it.
Does anyone know how to fix the mistake?
Thank you.
Hi I’m trying to put an image as icon of the app but I’m not getting it.
Does anyone know how to fix the mistake?
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Add your full pubspec.yaml

Comment: paste your pubspec code

Comment: Hello I’ve pasted the code on top

Answer (score 0):

You have indented your `flutter_icon:` inside the fuller dependency, remove the extra indent, in pubspec.yaml indent works on 2 space

And also you need to add the image source under assets